# Messaging system with sql

Tags: sql-server

i'm working on a message system which i want both users to see the messages they've sent to each other in ascending our, i have this code but doesn't seem to work. when one logs on he's only able to see the messages he's sent to the other user an can't see his. But he should be able to the one's he's sent and one's he's recieved by the other user

```
SELECT *
FROM messaging
WHERE sender_id = MMColParam1 AND reciever_id = MMColParam2 OR sender_id = MMColParam3 AND reciever_id=MMColParam4
```

Comment: You should use parenthesis - this improves readibility and maybe already fixes your issue. Also without any schemas one cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use brackets around your `AND/OR`s. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) SQL will evaluate them from left to right which means that your statement is the same as

```
WHERE (((sender_id = MMColParam AND reciever_id = MMColParam2) OR sender_id = MMColParam3) AND reciever_id=MMColParam4)
```

What you're probably after is

```
WHERE (sender_id = MMColParam AND reciever_id = MMColParam2) OR (sender_id = MMColParam3 AND reciever_id=MMColParam4)
```